# Relation between keyboard and javafx gui (setOnKeyPressed)

Tags: javafx, keyboard

I want to bind actions of JavaFX buttons to keyboard keys.

[image]

I want the following functionality:

- When I click 1, the action for "Select one file" should trigger
- When I click 9, the action for "Select multi file" should trigger
- When I click Enter, the action for "OK" button should trigger
- When I click Esc, the action for "Cancel" button should trigger

Comment: Instead of just using a single button, a better approach would be to use a combination of keys i.e. press ALT + KEY to trigger the button's action. This will also help you to add Mnemonics or Accelerators to ease the process.

Comment: My purpose is create a small keyboard so I need how to call all the keys in the keyboard,   , when I clicked in A button it display in textArea A, and when I clicked in a button it display in textArea a, and the same for all the other keys

Comment: I do not understand your comment. Do you want to show the text in the TextArea when the button is pressed or do you want it to fire the button?

Answer (score 1):

Todo this you could use `EventFilters`

If you want to have have it triggered only when one key is pressed:

```
addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->
{
    if(event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DIGIT1))
    {
        System.out.println("1 Pressed");

        //Then either call the method directly
        selectOneFile();

        //Or fire the button
        selectOneFileBtn.fire();
    }
});
```

But as @ItachiUchiha (and I) recommend, you should use a combination of keys:

```
addEventFilter(KeyEvent.KEY_PRESSED, event ->
{
    if(event.isAltDown() && event.getCode().equals(KeyCode.DIGIT1))
    {
        System.out.println("Alt + 1 Pressed");

        //Then again, either call the method directly
        selectOneFile();

        //Or fire the button
        selectOneFileBtn.fire();
    }
});
```